# gmap review not showing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

i want to fetch and display the review of a shop.
here is my code
      `
      
     
     
           Google review

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/stevenmonson
      /googleReviews/master/google-places.css">
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1
  /jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/stevenmonson/googleReviews/6e8f0d79
 /google-places.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&
 key=AIzaSyAhsK9C6YGLyA6bd7YIG-OrOmDwNbnU3mw&signed=true&
 libraries=places"></script>
                   jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
                    $("#google-reviews").googlePlaces({
                     placeId: 'ChIJiXw7QQtxAjoRIB3UaxmjWKs',
                     render: ['reviews'],
                     max_rows:4
                     });
                  });
 </body>
 </html>`
```

i have created an api from the google map section. and the place id i have found from the store map review. 
the error shows that:

> Google Maps JavaScript API error: RefererNotAllowedMapError
>   https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#referer-not-allowed-map-error
>   Your site URL to be authorized:
>   http://thearham.in/development/computercare/google.php

is it necessary to enable billing information in the google account to access map ???

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. Since July 16th this year Google Maps services are no longer free. 
You need to give them you billing info in order for your API key to work.

Comment: Did you register your app as a user of google maps api?

Comment: just found out that the billing info was not there.

Comment: just added the billing info.  now the error sows that: Google Maps JavaScript API error: RefererNotAllowedMapError

Answer (score 0):

finnaly the error has been resolved. the thing was i need to activate the maps java script api enabled.
that means if we want to show review then we have to enable the two area in google.
1. places api 
2.maps for javascript api